# PostgreSQL streaming replication with slots works for one slave, but not for another slave

Tags: postgresql, replication

**Master (10.0.0.1):**

Edit postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = logical
max_wal_senders = 3
max_replication_slots = 3
hot_standby = on
```

Edit pg_hba.conf

```
host    replication     postgres    0.0.0.0/0   trust
```

Create a replication slot for the slave

```
select * from pg_create_physical_replication_slot('master');
```

**Slave #1 (10.0.0.2):**

Remove 9.4/main directory

```
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
```

Do a base backup of the master

```
pg_basebackup -P -R -X stream -c fast -h 10.0.0.1 -U postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
```

Edit recovery.conf

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=postgres host=10.0.0.1 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
primary_slot_name = 'master'
```

Copy conf files from master

```
rsync -av user@10.0.0.1:/etc/postgresql/ /etc/postgresql/
```

Restart cluster

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.4 main restart
```

**Slave #2 (10.0.0.3):**

Same steps as for slave #1 except the ip of the slave is different.

**The problem:** A change on the master propagates the change onto slave #1 but not slave #2. Tried rebooting slave #2 and setting up again from a fresh install but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from a comment left by the question author. Feel free to edit to improve*</sub>

Nevermind, I fixed it. There needs to be one replication slot per slave. I added another replication slot "master2". So slave #1 is using the "master" replication slot and slave #2 is using the "master2" replication slot. Works fine now.